# Laravel, get all post comments of selected user

Tags: laravel, comments, polymorphism

How can I take all user post comments?

I'm already using morphTo() method between comments and posts/profiles to have all comments i one db table.

I tried to use hasMany('Comment', 'author_id') method but i can't get only post comments with post title, id, slug.

Comment Model:

```
public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Post Model

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('Comment', 'commentable');
}
```

And what i want to do in view

```
@foreach ($profile->comments as $comment)
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Post Title HERE</a></td>
        <td>{{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: How is *$profile* defined?

Comment: $profile = $this->users->createModel()->findOrFail($id);